# Angular injection from different modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I get, this error

Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

when I try the following

HTML

```
<div ng-app="angularmodule">
    <div ng-controller="mycontroller">
        <div class="mydirective"  </div>
    </div>
```

Directive

```
angular
    .module('ui.module', [])
    .directive('mydirective', function () {

        //some directive stuff in here, restricted as ‘C’

            }
        };
    });
```

Factory

```
angular
    .module('dataLayerModule', [])
    .factory('datalayer', [$http],

        function (http) {

         //some method in here that uses http request
            return factory;
        });
```

Controller

```
angular
    .module(‘angularmodule’, [‘ui.module', 'dataLayerModule'])
     .controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', 'datalayer', function ($scope, datalayer) {

        //this is dependent on two modules being injected i.e. ‘ui.module','dataLayerModule'
    }]);
```

If I strip out the factory  ('dataLayerModule') module injection from the just above it works  e.g

```
    angular
        .module('angularmodule’, ['ui.module'])
        .controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {


        }]);
```

The problem is my 'dataLayerModule’ injection and it’s 'datalayer' factory are not being injected, I think.
The angular javascript code above are in different files but are correctly loaded in the html.

What I’m trying to do is inject the factory into the controller, the factory will be responsible for getting json data via ajax

The reason for these different modules is that the 'ui-module' comes from a 3rd party which I have no control over.

If anyone can create a plunker, with this injection just functioning/loading correctly I'd be so grateful, this is driving me mad

Comment: The issue is probably inside your 'dataLayerModule’

Comment: even if I strip the code from the dataLayer it still errors, the $http as well

Comment: quotation marks that you use, look different, check it please

Comment: that's a typo from entering the text in word first before coping into the textareas. I'll see what I can do in the morning, it's getting late now in the UK, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `factory` declaration, you said:

```
.factory('datalayer', [$http], function (http) {})
```

but I think this is what you want:

```
.factory('datalayer', ['$http', function (http) {}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in how you're injecting the `$http` dependency into your factory that most likely are breaking the factory code. You are not currently including the factory method within the array where your dependencies are injected. There are also no quotation marks around `$http` and it's not being injected into the factory correctly (there is no `$` symbol when it is passed as a param to the function). It should be:

```
angular
.module('dataLayerModule', [])
.factory('datalayer', ['$http', function($http) {

    //some method in here that uses http request
    return factory;
}]);
```

*Alternative syntax*

With the syntax above (including dependencies and the function within an array), it can be difficult to spot these kinds of errors. An alternative and more explicit syntax is to pass the function name into the factory method and declare the function further down.

```
angular
    .module('dataLayerModule', [])
    .factory('datalayer', dataLayer);

dataLayer.$inject = ['$http'];

function dataLayer($http) {

    //some method in here that uses http request
    return factory;
}
```